# connect two points of a plot with another line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I want to connect two points in a data frame plot with another line and add it to the plot:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
days = [datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime(2016, 1, 2),datetime(2016, 1, 3),datetime(2016, 1, 4)]
dt_ind = pd.DatetimeIndex(days)
data = np.random.randn(4,2)
cols = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,dt_ind,cols)
df['A'].plot(figsize=(12,4), sort_columns=True)
```

here is the data frame:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWoaL.png)

and the plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3flRv.png)

how is that possible? for example add a line from point 2 to point 4 (or any two points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use matplotlib's plt.subplots() function to return a fig and ax object, so you can then add separate lines to your ax.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
days = [datetime(2016, 1, 1),
        datetime(2016, 1, 2), 
        datetime(2016, 1, 3), 
        datetime(2016, 1, 4)]

dt_ind = pd.DatetimeIndex(days)
data = np.random.randn(4,2)
cols = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,dt_ind,cols)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['A'], color='red')
ax.plot([df.index[1], df.index[3]],
        [df['A'][1], df['A'][3]], color='blue')
```

[image]